# vim command for adding Parentheses efficiently

Tags: vim

what is the vim command can put something into Parentheses efficiently and then I can use `.` to repeat it? ?

for example, `data['max']` to `(data['max'])`

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. A specific example of what you'd like to do would help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. visually select your text:

   ```
   viW
   ```
2. change it with the opening parenthesis, followed by the selected text, followed by the closing parenthesis:

   ```
   c(<C-r><C-o>")<Esc>
   ```

If you are confident with text-objects, this can be done in one step:

```
ciW(<C-r><C-o>")<Esc>
```

which can be repeated with `.`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using two plugins for this. Tim Pope's [`vim-surround`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) and [`vim-repeat`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat).

Just follow the links and install those plugins.

Inorder to put parenthesis around a word, just do `ysiw)`

Otherwise, select text in visual mode, press <kbd>S</kbd>(Capital S) and type in paranthesis

Answer (score 2):

You can use a map for that.

```
   :nmap \. I(<ESC>A)
```

You can put this line in your ~/.vimrc file.

When you press `\` and `.` in normal mode, it will  add a opening bracket at the start of the line and closing bracket at the end of the line.

Assuming that you are using a language like Tcl and surround the hash element with a bracket, 
You can try this by keeping the cursor anywhere on the hash name,

```
    : nmap \. bi(<Esc>f]li)
```

This will surround the expected one with circular braces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map in vimrc:

```
xnoremap <leader>a <ESC>`>a)<ESC>`<i(<ESC>
```

And use `<leader>` and `a` to add parentheses efficiently